# Can we fetch data(or insert data to the database) using any of the Wordpress plugins from a iphone app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, wordpress

There is a wordpress powered website ,, and i need to develop a native iphone app for the same site , since am born new to the social networks development, i have spent so much of time to find a plugin to do data transaction , but  i could not find any , my question is, can we use any of the wordpress plugins to fetch data from the remote database (or to insert data to the remote database)  from an iphone app??  if not, is there any other powerful methods to access remote database without using the web services...please help me out ,thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress plugins are server-side pieces of code that affect how the WordPress installation behaves.  They don't run as part of a client application.  If you're building a native app, you will need to create Objective-C that talks to the server.

A quick Google search gave me this as a likely source of information about how to communicate:
http://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_WordPress_API

Comment: thanx for ur time @phillip,,,i have reffered that link ,can we use those components (wp.getPost,wp.getPosts,wp.newPost) in our iphone app (in obj c ?) i think those functions r only for php

Comment: XML-RPC is just a network communication method and you can use it from Objective-C.  The information at that link describes the kind of remote features you can access from your client.

Comment: @ Phillip Can u pls tell me how can i access those from obj c

Comment: You first need to understand how XML-RPC works.  Here's a link that describes it and also contains other links to existing Objective-C frameworks for it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xml-rpc  (There are other libraries available on github; I don't know which is the best.)  Once you have that working, then the WordPress API should make more sense.